# #Value error coding a VBA function for an asian option

Tags: excel, vba

Im trying to code the pricing of a asian option with the payoff: MAX(Geometric mean(price path) - exercise;0), using monte carlo, but cant get my VBA code to work.

S0, current stock price50 X,
exercise price 30
time to option expires 1year
exercise    0,4
interest rate   8 % ,
mean stock return   15 %
standard deviation of stock return  22 %
n, number of sub-intervals  250
Delta t 0,0040
Up over 1 sub-interval  1,0146
Down over 1 sub-interval    0,9868
Interest over 1 sub-interval    1,0003

```
Function MC_Av_PRICE_Asian_call_geomean(Initial, exercise, Up, Down, _
    Interest, Periods, Runs)
    Dim PricePath() As Double
    ReDim PricePath(Periods + 1)
    
    'Risk-neutral probabilities
    PiUp = (Interest - Down) / (Up - Down)
    PiDown = 1 - PiUp
         
    Temp = 0
      
    For Index = 1 To Runs
        'Generate path
        For i = 1 To Periods
            PricePath(0) = Initial
            pathprob = 1
            If Rnd > PiDown Then
              PricePath(i) = PricePath(i - 1) _
              * Up
              Else:
              PricePath(i) = PricePath(i - 1) * _
              Down
            End If
         Next i
         
        PriceAverage = Application.WorksheetFunction.GeoMean(PricePath)
            Callpayoff = Application.Max _
        (PriceAverage - exercise, 0)
            Temp = Temp + Callpayoff
        
   Next Index
   
   MC_Av_PRICE_Asian_call_geomean = (Temp / Interest ^ Periods) / _
       Runs
   
End Function
```

But the result of running the function gives a #VALUE! error regardless of what i choose as input.

I have been studying this error for some hours now, would really appreciate, if someone smarter than me could help me out here!

Best

Comment: It's easier to debug if you call this from a subroutine, instead of as a UDF.

Comment: And in English that would be? :-)

Comment: Create a new subroutine, `Sub Foo`. Within it, use for example `Debug.Print MC_Av_PRICE_Asian_call_geomean(....)`, passing the parameters you're currently using when running the function from a cell as `=MC_Av_PRICE_Asian_call_geomean(...)`. I can explain further if that doesn't make sense. Calling this from a subroutine will make it easier to pinpoint the problematic line(s).

Comment: Im not too familiar with coding in VBA, so I do not fully understand what you mean. Could you show an example of what you mean, that is implement the debugging procedure into the code? I do now know how to do that. Thank you so much for helping out!